# How to kick off puppet jobs via http api

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

Good day, I'm trying to figure out how I would go about telling Puppet (master?) to spin up a new VM and provision it with the specified settings. Basically, I have a form that a user fills out and then upon submit, those settings get sent to the Puppet intermediary that then does some sort of api call (http?) that starts the Puppet provisioning process.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What has your research indicated so far?

Comment: @DeerHunter I've found some Puppet Master HTTP API but I does not appear that new images can be kicked off. I've also found an application called The Foreman but that seems rather robust for this simple need.